# Under what conditions is the compositum of two rational cubic Kummer extensions a rational function field?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, fields, function-fields, kummer-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p > 3$ and $F = k(x)$ be the rational function field in the variable $x$. Consider two Kummer extensions $F_1 = F(\sqrt[3]{g_1})$, $F_2 = F(\sqrt[3]{g_2})$ of degree $3$, where $g_1, g_2 \in F^*$. Suppose that $F_1, F_2$ are also rational, that is $F_1 = k(x_1)$, $F_2 = k(x_2)$ for some $x_1 \in F_1$, $x_2 \in F_2$.

Under what conditions is the compositum $F_1F_2 = k(\sqrt[3]{g_1}, \sqrt[3]{g_2})$ a rational function field?

Comment: Should that not be a simple application of Riemann-Hurwitz? It only depends on the number of distinct ramification points, which one can read off from $g_1$ and $g_2$.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially never. By Hurwitz formula, the covering corresponding to $F_i/F$ (for $i=1,2$) has 2 branch points $a_i,b_i\in \mathbb{P}^1$. The covering corresponding to $F_1F_2/F$ has degree 9. If $(a_1,b_1)\cap (a_2,b_2)=\varnothing$, it has 4 branch points in $\mathbb{P}^1$, with 3 double ramification points above each of these; this makes genus 4. If  $(a_1,b_1)\cap (a_2,b_2)$ consists of one point, we get genus 1. Finally if $(a_1,b_1)= (a_2,b_2)$, we have $F_1=F_2=F_1F_2$ — it is rational but this is of course a trivial case.

Incidentally, note that your functions $g_1$ and $g_2$ have only one zero and one pole, so they are homographies.